# TravisCI - Asp.net Deployment to Linux Server

Tags: asp.net, mono, continuous-integration, travis-ci, xbuild

I'm able to build my asp.net 4 (MVC) Applicaton via TravisCI.org, but I'm not able to "copy" the output from travis to my linux server.

I would like to solve this with a *.sh file, but I have no idea how to start this and where the files from TravisCI - Build are located.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you might be looking for is a [custom deployment](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/custom/). But Travis provides a wide range of other deployment targets.

When you have an FTP server running on your Linux box, then you might simply zip your build artifacts and upload them with cURL to your FTP server.

Travis allows encrypted environment vars, which you need for FTP credentials.
The easiest way to create secure vars, is to utilize the travis gem, which encrypts a string and adds it to your .travis.yml.

```
gem install --user travis
travis encrypt MY_SECRET_ENV=super_secret -r my_username/my_repo
```

The deployments happens in the `after_success` section.
You can add the tasks to perform your deployment directly there or add a call to a `deploy.sh` with the commands to execute.

Just copy and paste from the [FTP example](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/custom/#FTP).

---

> where the files from TravisCI - Build are located

Hmm, it's your build script. You have the choice to place them where you want.
I tend to use a `build` folder, which i zip and deploy.
Take a look at your Travis build log.
Or simply list your files and folders to find them...

```
- sudo ls -alh /home/travis/build/repo/repo/*
```